# How to search patterns in a single line from a file in unix

Tags: unix, command

Suppose I have file with a single line.

```
/a/n/v//9.3/b/ld  --verbose -o o/c/f/r1 -r o/c/f/fn.o o/c/f/fyt.o L/fs/ed/pl/tls/oe -L/apps/ose/5.5.3//lib/powerpc -lc -lrt -lm -lcp  -lel -lip -lubs -lpp -lpc /a/oe/5.3//g3/l/g.3/nf/libgcov.a  -lrds -l00_ex -lmcu /a/n/v//9.3/b/ld  --verbose -o o/ce/wef/r34
```

I want to search for the pattern starting with "-l" and arrange it in the below order in another file.

```
-lc 
-lrt 
-lm 
-lcp  
-lel 
-lip 
-lubs 
-lpp 
-lpc 
-lrds 
-l00_ex 
-lmcu
```

What command could be used to search the pattern mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
echo "/a/n/v//9.3/b/ld  --verbose -o o/c/f/r1 -r o/c/f/fn.o o/c/f/fyt.o L/fs/ed/pl/tls/oe -L/apps/ose/5.5.3//lib/powerpc -lc -lrt -lm -lcp  -lel -lip -lubs -lpp -lpc /a/oe/5.3//g3/l/g.3/nf/libgcov.a  -lrds -l00_ex -lmcu /a/n/v//9.3/b/ld  --verbose -o o/ce/wef/r34" \
| awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ /^-l/) print $i }}' | sort
```

**output**

```
-l00_ex
-lc
-lcp
-lel
-lip
-lm
-lmcu
-lpc
-lpp
-lrds
-lrt
-lubs
```

Needless to say, if you don't want the output sorted for some reason, just remove `|sort` on the end. It will then print the arguments in the order listed on the cmd-line. (I suppose sometimes that would be important).

I'm using a standard awk idom, of iterating per element over the provided input

```
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
```

the `i` is a tmp variable, `NF` means **N** umber (of) **F** ields, meaning the num-of-fields in the current line. The test is done with regular expression test

```
if ($i ~ /^-l/ )
```

where `$i` is the value of the i'th position in the input, and `^`  indicates "must be at the front of the string", while `-l` matches any of the inputs you have provided.

`echo`ing your data to `awk` via a pipe shows that `awk` is very comfortable reading from std-in, so you can replace `echo` with `grep yourSearchtarget yourFile | awk ...` or any other command that will return the lines you need for processing.

IHTH

Comment: Your answer was useful and it works the way I expected. When I used the echo command,it comes up as "argument list too long". So I tried to use "cat" command  

cat <filename_with_single_big_line> | | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ /^-l/) print $i }}' 

Thanks a lot for your timely help.